# Read the file in an array in matlab

Tags: matlab

```
1 ::  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
2 ::  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
3 ::  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
4 ::  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
5 ::  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
6 ::  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
7 ::  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
8 ::  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
9 ::  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
10 ::  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1
11 ::  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
12 ::  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
```

I have the above text file. I want to read this file in Matlab and want to store
the content of the file in an array in two columns. In first column the
sequence number and in the other column the 16 bit pattern as follows

```
1     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
2     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
3     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
4     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
5     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
6     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
7    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: How do you expect to fit 16 columns of data into the second column?

Comment: You can either treat this as text (e.g. `'7' '0000000000000111'`) or use cell array or a table.

Answer (score 0):

If the indices are ordered like `1:n` (or any other know order), you can use this:

```
fileID = fopen('bin16.txt');
raw = fscanf(fileID,'%s');
fclose(fileID);
colon_ind = strfind(raw,'::');
data = table((1:numel(colon_ind)).',...
    cell(numel(colon_ind),1),...
    'VariableNames',{'Index','Pattern'});
counter = 1;
for k = colon_ind
    data.Pattern(counter,:) = {raw(k+2:k+17)};
    counter = counter+1;
end
```

and get this:

```
data = 
    Index         Pattern      
    _____    __________________
     1       '0000000000000011'
     2       '0000000000000101'
     3       '0000000000001001'
     4       '0000000000000110'
     5       '0000000000010001'
     6       '0000000000001010'
     7       '0000000000000111'
     8       '0000000000010010'
     9       '0000000000001100'
    10       '0000000000001011'
    11       '0000000000100001'
    12       '0000000000010100'
```

If the index column is not ordered you can use something like this:

```
fileID = fopen('bin16b.txt','r');
raw = fscanf(fileID,'%s');
C = textscan(raw,'%s','delimiter','::');
fclose(fileID);
N = (size(C{1},1)-1)/2;
data = table(zeros(N,1),cell(N,1),...
    'VariableNames',{'Index','Pattern'});
data.Index(1) = str2num(C{1}{1,1});
for k = 1:N
    if k>1
        data.Index(k) = str2num(C{1}{k*2-1,:}(17:end));
    end
    data.Pattern(k,:) = {C{1}{k*2+1,:}(1:16)};
end
```

To obtain (with some arbitrary data I entered):

```
Index         Pattern      
_____    __________________
54       '0000000000000011'
 6       '0000000000000101'
 3       '0000000000001001'
 4       '0000000000000110'
 5       '0000000000010001'
92       '0000000000001010'
 7       '0000000000000111'
35       '0000000000010010'
 9       '0000000000001100'
10       '0000000000001011'
11       '0000000000100001'
12       '0000000000010100'
```

---

**EDIT**

If the '::' in the file can be deleted before, then you can use:

```
text = load ('bin16b.txt', '-ascii');
data = table(text(:,1),text(:,2:end),...
    'VariableNames',{'Index','Pattern'});
```

and get:

```
data = 
    Index       Pattern   
    _____    _____________
    54       [1x16 double]
     6       [1x16 double]
     3       [1x16 double]
     4       [1x16 double]
     5       [1x16 double]
    92       [1x16 double]
     7       [1x16 double]
    35       [1x16 double]
     9       [1x16 double]
    10       [1x16 double]
    11       [1x16 double]
    12       [1x16 double]
```

where each cell in the pattern column is like:

```
>> data.Pattern(1,:)
ans =
  Columns 1 through 14
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
  Columns 15 through 16
     1     1
```

Comment: Hi, it works for me, but its I had used load file option as it stores my values as integers.