# Search a position of pattern in a cell array

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array as below which contains 17000 such combinations.

```
'0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1'

'0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1'

'0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1'

'0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0'

'0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1'

'0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0'

'0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0'

'0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0'

'0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1'

'0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0'

'0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0'
```

I want to search the patterns in an array in a loop. I am interested in the position of that pattern in the cell array using Matlab. I had tried strcmp() function  for comparison but it takes lots of time as each pattern is compared with 17000 elements of the cell array.

Is there any fastest method  to search a pattern in cell array?

Comment: why don't you convert the strings to ints?

Comment: The community recently discussed [the addition of urgent begging to questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) and decided that it prefers posts without such requests.

Comment: You can read the data from your file as a numeric array rather than a string in a cell array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39477051/read-the-file-in-an-array-in-matlab

Comment: Hi, i am using textscan to read the above patterns from the file. Instead of that can anyone suggest me how to read the above patterns in a numeric array. I want to search a specific pattern  from the above array of 17000 elements, I am interested in the position of the specific  pattarn in the array.And the search should be fast.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`bin2dec`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bin2dec.html) to convert all entries in the cell array to integers, then convert the search pattern to int as well and search for ints

Comment: Thanks.. But i don't want to convert it into decimal ewant to compare the same patterns.Also the problem is that my pattern to be search is having double spacing and the cell array has a single spacing in between the elements in the array. How to solve this problem.